# sudo problem with STAF

Tags: linux, sudo

I'm new to Linux. I've just installed the [STAF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STAF), and I can run STAF with my account, but when I try to run use root account, I get:

> sudo: STAF: command not found

Here is some of my machine information:

```
which sudo

    /usr/bin/sudo

echo $PATH

    /usr/local/staf/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/eric/eclipse
```

What is the explanation? Why can't `sudo` find the command?

Comment: What does "sudo env | grep PATH" output?

Comment: sudo env | grep PATH
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is on this (duplicate) question,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257616/sudo-changes-path-why

Comment: Here's the post: This is an annoying function of sudo on ubuntu. Note this doesn't happen on fedora for example as sudo is not built with the --with-secure-path option there. To work around this "problem" on ubuntu I do the following in my "~/.bashrc": alias sudo='sudo env PATH=$PATH' ...note this will work for commands that don't reset the $PATH themselves. However `su' resets it's $PATH so you must use -p to tell it not to: sudo su -p

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the binary is in /usr/local/staf/bin, does "`sudo /usr/local/staf/bin/STAF`" work?

And, to rule out the obvious: the binary name is actually all uppercase?

What operating system is this?  Do you know if anyone has tweaked your sudoers.conf?  I assume it is changing your environment variables.  In all default setups that I've seen though, $PATH isn't changed.

Comment: Yes, the command with full path works. I may have understand this a bit. It's probably because the /usr/local/staf/bin is not in the $PATH of root account, right? BTW, I'm using Ubuntu9.04 and I want to check if I'm correct, what is the root password? I've just installed the OS with my name as default account.

Comment: @eric2323223: In a default Ubuntu install sudo wants your user account password, not the root password. To change the root password do "sudo bash" and then "passwd".

Answer (score 0):

The proper PATH is obviously not set for the root user.